# Can anyone explain these errors?

Tags: android

[I am trying to publish an android app and I am getting these 2 errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaXom.png)

Not sure what they mean and how to sort this out.

Comment: It means if your app crashes, you won't see a good readable crash log because all the class and method names are changed to short character sequences. Android Studio generates a file which you can upload which helps to translate those crashlogs into a better readable form. Check out this documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#decode-stack-trace

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.